# How to achevie the Polymorphism progarmme in PHP?

Tags: php

Hi, I'm trying to write code to achieve php polymorphism. I don't know where there is a mistake in the code. It shows the error in "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Sample::a() ". Here is my code. Kindly solve this problem.

```
 <?php
 class Sample
{
public function a()
{
 echo "hi";
}
public function a($chr)
{
 for ($chr=0;$chr<10;$chr++)
 echo $chr;
}
 public function a($b,$c)
 {
for($g=$b;$g<$c;$g++)
echo $g
}
}

$s=new Sample();
$s->a();
$s->a($chr);
$s->a(1,10);
?>
```

Comment: that's not polymorphism, that's method overloading. PHP doesn't support it (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

See the above link. I think it will help you.

Answer (score 5):

PHP does not support method overloading...unfortunatly!

There are some funky methods to achievement something that feels like overloading, like using magic methods or wrapping sub-method calls. These don't even come close to the real thing though.

Comment: well to be fair it supports it, but only with core functions and if you active it setting `mbstring.func_overload` to a positive value (each value activates function overload for specific core functions). But aside from that yup, you can't overload user-defined functions!

Comment: You cannot really call that function overloading, more like function forwarding.

Comment: yup that's true, but it's the term PHP uses in its documentation.

Comment: They do, but they do encapsulate it with single quotes. They know they are lying haha.

Comment: Ok guys really thanks for all who have participate this conversation. Finally I am getting an idea. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

This is not [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) but the following:

```
class A {
    public function foo() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B {
    public function foo() {
        return 2;
    }
}

$items = array(new A(), new B());

echo $items[0]->foo();
echo $items[1]->foo();
```

Comment: This is polymorphic overriding, author speaks about polymorphic overloading

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support method overloading the way you've asked for.

The closest you can get is using dynamic arguments to fake it. Something like the following:

```
class dynamic {
    public function example() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        switch(count($args)) {
            case 1 : return $this->example_1arg($args[0]);
            case 2 : return $this->example_2args($args[0],$args[1]);
            //etc..
        }
    }
    private function example_1arg($arg1) {
        //....
    }
    private function example_2args($arg1,$arg2) {
        //....
    }
}
```

That still doesn't get you proper method overloading, because this example doesn't take into account data types. You could wire that in to a certain extent using `instanceof`, but you won't be able to go the whole way, since PHP also doesn't (yet) support type hinting for primitive types.